# Visual Studio Async CTP must be installed on client machines ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-ctp

If i use Async/Await in my code, must i install the CTP on each client machine or just on machine where i develop ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion its not a good idea to use this CTP in production code. But as well as I know this is compiler feature, so you need only .Net 4.0 installed on client PC.

**Update:**
There is some special .NET Framework 4.0 update called “.NET Framework Async CTP”. It could be required at client machine.

Comment: Ok thanks, but that it's ok. When we deploy our product, all clients have .Net 4 installed (our product is based on Silverlight 4).

Comment: See my update. I wouldn't recommend you to use CTPs at production.

Comment: -1: That is precisely the question. Is that update required on the client machine? If yes, is there a way to install that update?

Comment: For reference: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983 (Async CTP 3) states: " This license does not constitute encouragement for you to use the CTP for your production code. The CTP remains an unsupported and use-at-your-own-risk Technology Preview. However, we’ve received many requests from developers to use the CTP for production code, and so have changed the license to allow that."

Answer (score 2):

Even though I agree that it is not recommended to use CTP type libraries in 'production', you should just have to included whatever dll(s) you referenced in your project with your exe that you deploy to your client.  Just like any other reference.